# Alias not updated after using source .bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, shell, alias

I am testing the bash behavior on login (terminal 1), but I got confused about its interaction with alias:

I opened with `vim .bashrc` and add this line :

```
alias ls='ls -l'
```

and save it with `:x`
then  I used `source .bashrc` to simulate a new login session and I found it in the aliases list

But I removed the alias from .bashrc and use `source .bashrc` again I saw that `alias ls='ls -l'` was still available. On the other hand, opening new shell terminal (terminal 2) the problem was solved.

Question: Why `alias ls='ls -l'` was not removed on the first terminal ?

Comment: `source` does not "simulate a new login" it just executes the operations in the file in the current shell.  None of those operations removed the alias.

Comment: I mean instead of login again I used source. But the rest of your sentence is not understood, could you please explain more ?

Comment: `source .bashrc` is basically the same as copy-pasting the contents `.bashrc` into your shell. If you copy-paste `echo Hello; alias ls='ls -l'` then you would expect Hello to be written and an alias to be defined. If you afterwards copy-paste `echo Hello`, you would NOT expect the `ls` alias to disappear. Same thing here.

Comment: Thank you so so much, now it is clear :)

Comment: Please note the comment in the bash man page, which I believe predates 1996: "For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions."  IMO, "almost every purpose" is an understatement; there is no need to use aliases.

Comment: @WilliamPursell With some effort, I can find some corner cases where there may still be useful, hence the "almost every", but TBH I do agree with your "there is no need to use aliases"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sourcing `.bashrc` doesn't clear what you have defined so far. It just adds the definitions it contains to your current environment.

If you want to undefine a given alias, just type:

```
$ unalias ls
$ source .bashrc
```

If you want to undefine all aliases:

```
$ unalias -a
$ source .bashrc
```

Finally, if you want to start over with a brand new shell, you can of course close your session and reopen one, but here is an almost identical command in case this is not that easy (ssh) or undesirable:

```
$ exec bash
```

(you may also add the `-l` option to simulate a login shell, thus reading your `~/.bash_profile` file)